# Multiple Slicing in a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython, slice

Say for example if I have a data frame with columns A - Z.

1. I want to slice column "J" and get back all the columns A - Z  excluding the column "J".
2. I want to slice all columns between A - Z and only get back column "J"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), for return `J` column need convert `Series` to `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'J':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  F  J
0  1  4  7  1  7  5
1  2  5  8  3  4  3
2  3  6  9  5  3  6

print (df.pop('J'))
0    5
1    3
2    6
Name: J, dtype: int64

dfJ = df.pop('J').to_frame()
print (dfJ)
   J
0  5
1  3
2  6

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  F
0  1  4  7  1  7
1  2  5  8  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  3
```

---

Another solution:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'J']
print (df[cols])
   A  B  C  D  F
0  1  4  7  1  7
1  2  5  8  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  3

print (df[['J']])
   J
0  5
1  3
2  6
```